# how do I add an icon to an Android button in XML

Tags: xml, android-layout, button

so I have been trying to do this for a while now, I seached google and all but I do not seem to get what I need.
I am writing an app and basically create 4 buttons.
What I want to do is place an Icon at the background of the button and write text like in weather apps where you have the cloud with next and also change the fontstyle of the text. I found icons [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome).how do I do this?
this is what I wrote:

`

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="WEATHER STATION"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/weathericon"
        android:background="@drawable/weather"
        android:id="@+id/weather_station" />`
```

unfortunately I cant put images yet.

Comment: what you have tired?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

android:background="@drawable/weather"

in your code with

android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/[your background image]"

Answer (score 0):

Just call setBackgroundDrawable() on a Button to set the background of the button.
The text will appear on the button with background image.